# Class 'PHPMailer' not found

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send my mails via phpmailer. So I placed the `Exception.php`, `PHPMailer.php` and `SMTP.php` into a directory called `phpmailer`.

When I try this php tells me `Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /path/to/file.php on line 9`

Here my snippet

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

What is the problem? Why php cant find the PHPMailer class?

Comment: make sure the phpmailer folder is in the same folder as that php script.

Comment: The includes give no errors.The folder is in the same path as the script.

Comment: if you're using a new version of phpmailer try `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` and `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;`

Comment: @xandev this works :)

Comment: One word: namespace.

Comment: some people down-vote just for the fun of it, this is not facebook (grow up)